# Php регистрация + функция js + форма html

Tags: php, регистрация, form, javascript

Добрый День. Такой вот вопрос.. мучаюсь уже долго.
Есть html страница с формой:

```
<div id="regForm" class="reg">

            <div id="signup">
            <form>
        <fieldset>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

            Логин:<br />
            <input type = "text" name = "login" id="regLogin" placeholder = "Введите Логин" pattern=".{3,}" placeholder="Минимум 3 символа" title="Минимум 3 символа" required="" />
            <p class="validation01">
                        <span class="invalid">Минимум 3 символа</span>
                        <span class="valid">Логин введен корректно</span>
            </p>
            <br />
            <br />
            Пароль:<br />
            <input type = "password" name = "password" id="regPassword" placeholder = "Введите Пароль" title="Минимум 5 символов" pattern="(?=^.{5,}$)(?![.\n]).*" required=""/>
            <p class="validation02">
                        <span class="invalid">Минимум 5 символов</span>
                        <span class="valid">Пароль введен корректно</span>
                    </p>
            <br />
            <br />
            E-mail:<br />
            <input type = "email" name = "email" id = "regMail" placeholder="e.g. ryan@example.net" title="Введите корректный адрес электронной почты" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$" required="">
            <p class="validation03">
                        <span class="invalid">Проверьте адрес почты</span>
                        <span class="valid">E-mail введен корректно</span>
            </p>
        </fieldset>

            <input type = "submit" name = "submit_reg" id = "submit_reg" value = "ЗАРЕГИСТРИРОВАТЬСЯ"/>
            </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div id = "regMessages">

            </div>
```

Также есть файл php.reg:

```
<?php

    require_once "functions.php";

    /* Получаем и обрабатываем данные */
    $login = escape($_POST['login']);
    if (strlen($login) == 0) exit;
    $password = escape($_POST['password']);
    if (strlen($password) == 0) exit;
    $mail = escape($_POST['mail']);
    if (strlen($mail) == 0) exit;
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db('auth_reg');
    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `mail`='{$mail}'";
    $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql)!=0)
{
    echo 'Данный e-mail уже зарегистрирован. Если Вы забыли Ваш пароль - воспользуйтесь опцией восстановления пароля.
<form action="/#res">
    <button type="submit" id="return">ВОССТАНОВИТЬ ПАРОЛЬ</button>
</form>';
}
else {

    $password_hash = md5($password.$hash); // Создаём хеш пароля

    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `mail`, `date`) VALUES ('$login', '$password_hash', '$mail', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())"); // Добавляем пользователя в базу данных

    if ($result)    
        $user = '
Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Теперь Вы можете войти на сайт как зарегистрированный пользователь.
<a href="#authForm"><input type="button" value="ВОЙТИ НА САЙТ" id="return"/></a>';

    else
        $user = '
Данный Логин уже существует! Попробуйте ещё раз или обратитесь к администратору.
<form action="/#regForm">
<input type=button onclick="window.location.reload()" id="return" type="submit" value="ВЕРНУТЬСЯ К РЕГИСТРАЦИИ">
</form>';

    echo $user;
    }
$query = "SELECT `mail`
                FROM `users`
                                 WHERE
                `login`='{$login}'
                LIMIT 1";
    $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$mail = $row['mail'];

//шлём пароль на это мыло

mail($mail, "Вы успешно зарегистрированы на нашем сайте", "Здравствуйте, Вы успешно зарегистрированы на нашем сайте. Запомните Ваш Логин. Если Вы забудете свой пароль - воспользуйтесь опцией восстановления пароля. Ваш логин на сайте: $login");

?>
```

И функция, которая вызывается на js.

```
$(function() {

$('#submit_reg').click(function() {
    var login = $('#regLogin').val();
    var password = $('#regPassword').val();
    var mail = $('#regMail').val();
    if (login == '' || password == '' || mail == '') {

    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url:        '/reg.php',
            type:       'POST',
            cache:      false,
            data:       {'login':login, 'password':password, 'mail':mail},
            dataType:   'html',
            success: function(data){
                $('#regForm').hide();
                $('#regMessages').html(data);
                $('#regMessages').show();
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Вопрос в следующем.
Все работает. Если убрать <form> </form> из html документа.
Однако, мне необходимо оставить тег <form>, так как сделал красивый стиль под него с проверкой введенных данных. Если оставить тег <form> - то когда нажимаем на ЗАРЕГИСТРИРОВАТЬСЯ форма просто обновляется и ничего не заносится в базу. 
Как можно избежать обновления формы?

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: и не забываем:

[deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @eicto, народ только на 5.4 неспешно переходит, а Вы уже весь форум засрали сообщениями о том, как в будущем PHP всё будет круто. Старые толстые проекты с mysql_ всё равно переводить никто не будет, а новички поковыряют PHP используя технологии, описанные в старых учебниках да и сбегут. А если не сбегут - то уже научаться к тому времени читать документацию.

Comment: так оно и в 5.4 устарело (не разрабатывается, никто не тратит на это силы) то что оно при это notify не кидает, ещё ничего не значит, уже в 5.3 не рекомендовали использовать это расширение. В том-то и дело, что новички плодят новый код с mysql_connect, потому-что даже в новых учебниках еще далеко не во всех про него забыли.

Comment: [вот здесь посмотрите когда были сделаны хоть сколько-то значиммые коммиты](https://github.com/php/php-src/blame/master/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c)

Comment: @eicto, я просто хочу сказать, что Ваши труды бесполезны и даже вредят. Не надо информировать о том, о чем написано в справке, там, где это не касается возникшей проблемы.

Comment: @Равнодушный, а я считаю наоборот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <form id="nosubmitform"> //Добавим к форме id

    ...

$("#nosubmitform").submit(function() {
   return false;
}); //Запретим отправку формы
```

Без формы кнопка не имеет действия по умолчанию. Когда же она становится частью формы - за кликом следует отправка.

Comment: preventDefault лучше [и вот почему](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/KfcAU/)

Comment: Сделал вот так: В html запихнул <script></script>

<body>
<script>
$("#nosubmitform").submit(function() {
   return false;
}); 
</script>

В форму добавил <form id="nosubmitform">

Но все равно. При заполнении формы происходит обновление полей и данные в базу не переносятся.

Comment: На самом деле Ваш пример предлагает переписать существующий код, пусть и минимально, а мой просто легко удаляемая костыль-вставка, в которой `return false` вместо `preventDefautl` используется лишь с целью экономии символов.

Comment: @Nabla, js-код должен быть внутри `$(function(){});`

Comment: ВСе) Спасибо) 
А другой способ - там много кода переписывать нужно?

Comment: Нет, не много. Просто теперь `$('#submit_reg').click(function() {` замените на `$("#nosubmitform").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();`, а мою "вставку" удалите.

Comment: Ваш вариант тоже рабочий. есть ли смысл менять?

Comment: Решайте сами. Разница будет только в одном: мой вариант ничего не сделает при попытке отправить форму клавишей `enter`, вариант же ericto в том же случае выполнит эквивалент текущего нажатия Вашей кнопки "ЗАРЕГИСТРИРОВАТЬСЯ".

Answer (score 0):

Во первых поставьте вместо клика по кнопке событие submit, во вторых, сделайте `preventDefault`:

```
$('#regForm form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //дальше все тоже самое
}
```

Answer (score 0):

замените <form> на <form id="form_reg">
и JS:

```
$(function() {

$('#form_reg').bind('submit', function() {
    var login = $('#regLogin').val();
    var password = $('#regPassword').val();
    var mail = $('#regMail').val();
    if (login == '' || password == '' || mail == '') {

    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url:        '/reg.php',
            type:       'POST',
            cache:      false,
            data:       {'login':login, 'password':password, 'mail':mail},
            dataType:   'html',
            success: function(data){
                $('#regForm').hide();
                $('#regMessages').html(data);
                $('#regMessages').show();
            }
        });
    }
return false;
});

});
```

Проверьте консоль чтоб небыло JS ошибок. Иначе скрипт не сработает и форма будет отправляться как в вашем случае. (ошибок не должно быть)

Comment: я же написал http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/KfcAU/ что preventDefault лучше (особенно в этом случае), зачем ваш ответ вообще непонятно, предыдущие два полностью покрывают все варианты.